# jQuery FancyBox late AJAX loading

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

In my app on fancybox element click I am AJAX loading an html page. But on that remote page I also have some javascript logic that uses AJAX (I know it's weird) to load some data on page load. Right now I don't want to show fancybox dialog or just keep showing loading animation until the data inside the remote page is fully loaded. 
Is there a way to do that?

What I have so far is really ugly - I load an empty page that is shown in the fancybox dialog and after a few seconds the content on that page is loaded. And because of that I have issues with dimensions and centering.

Comment: no offense, but sounds like you need to rethink this a little bit... why the double ajax? can't the second one be a curl (insert equivalent) call on the server side?

Comment: @JohnO, that's the problem, in this case I can't put any server side code, ASP.NET issues.

Answer (score 0):

`$.fancybox.showActivity()` and `$.fancybox.hideActivity()` are your friends. Call them sequentially as per your requirement. For example, you can call $.fancybox.showActivity() as a callback to your ajax call (when the initial box is displayed) to make the preloader/animation reappear and call $.fancybox.hideActivity() when the actual desired page/data is fetched from later ajax call, to make the animation disappear.

Comment: they don't do anything other than just showing animation, in my case I want to stop fancybox dialog from showing until the content is loaded.

Comment: You said: _Right now I don't want to show fancybox dialog **or just keep showing loading animation until the data inside the remote page is fully loaded.** Is there a way to do that?_ This way the loading animation will be shown until the final data is loaded!

Comment: @user253011, yes, I said that, but by 'just keep showing loading animation' I didn't mean show empty dialog and show animation on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

try callback like this:

`$('a.magical').fancybox({ 
  'callBackOnShow': function() { $('#fancybox-wrap').hide(); $.fancybox.showActivity(); }
});`

replace a.magical with your anchor id/class and add your fancybox configurations to it.

Comment: `$('#fancybox-wrap').hide()` is not an option for me, since fancybox dialog ui was already initialized at this stage and its width and height were already set. Changing the content of this dialog after this stage is a  really painful hack. I want fancybox's show function to be triggered after my own ajax complete event.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here is how it would work: **[BY USING CUSTOM AJAX]** initially make a custom jquery ajax call followed by the $.fancybox.showActivity(), on clicking the button for fancybox to fetch the interim page.  when the ajax call is made from the interim page, populate the data in a hidden div and make a sequel call for inline-typed (as opposed to the ajax one) fancybox opening call (use an hidden/empty anchor just to trigger the fancybox opening action and then call $('#hidden_a').click()). The preloader will be closed once the fancybox is shown.